# How do I get a custom Track for a Slider to draw extra thumbs?

Tags: wpf, slider, rangeslider

I'm working on a custom range slider with two thumbs. I've created a custom Track class and I've updated my slider's control template to support two thumbs. The thing is, I have not figured out why my new thumbs are not showing up.

My custom range class looks sorta like this:

```
public class RangeTrack : Track
{
    public RangeTrack() : base() { }

    public Thumb LeftThumb { get; set; }
    public ThumbRightThumb { get; set; }
}
```

And my edit to the [existing slider control template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753256%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) looks sorta like this:

```
    ...
    <local:RangeTrack x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
        <local:RangeTrack.LeftThumb>
            <Thumb Name="LeftThumb" Style="{StaticResource
                HorizontalSliderThumbStyle}" />
        </local:RangeTrack.LeftThumb>
        <local:RangeTrack.RightThumb>
            <Thumb Name="RightThumb" Style="{StaticResource 
                HorizontalSliderThumbStyle}" />
        </local:RangeTrack.RightThumb>
        <local:RangeTrack.Thumb>
            <Thumb Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource 
                HorizontalSliderThumbStyle}" />
        </local:RangeTrack.Thumb>
    </local:RangeTrack>
    ...
```

It still draws the original Thumb. But, not the two new ones I added.  I'm not sure if there is something special I should do in the RangeTrack's `OnRender`.

Edit:

I opened up PresentationFramework.dll in the IL Disassembler, and I noticed there's a property in System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track called ThumbCenterOffset, not sure if he is responsible for placing the Thumb in the correct spot.

Comment: I can't find my error in the xml, sorry it's not highlighting correctly. :(

Comment: if that's your entire class, you're doing it wrong. try [something basic](http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html)

Comment: no it's not. And I know something is wrong @_@

Comment: xD well, then let's see moar codez

Comment: the machine i develop on isn't connected to the webs, >_< so retyping it all is uber tedious, but in addition to what's up there I have 2 dependency properties for RangeStart and RangeEnd and I created CoreceCallbacks for each to ensure they stay in range. I tried messing around with OnRender and MeasureOverride, but I just can't figure out how the Track draws/places the original thumb :(

Comment: if I understood that part, I should be good to go. :)

Comment: in my experience with WPF, there's another way. if you insist on the current method, check out Track.cs with dotPeek and it may help your decision..